# ${n \choose k} \le ({en \over k})^k$ proof

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

$${n \choose k} \le \left({en \over k}\right)^k$$

Could anyone give me a hint how to prove this by induction on $k$? (I can prove it without induction)

Comment: Is $n$ taken to be some fixed natural number?

Comment: Yes, the inequality should be true for every n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking back at the answers that have been posted while I was working on this, I see that this is similar to AmWhy's argument. I will post it anyway since there is more detail (and color).

The base case is
$$
\binom{n}{1}=n\le en=\left(\frac{en}{1}\right)^1\tag{1}
$$
We avoid $k=0$ due to division by $0$.

Suppose the inequality is true for $\displaystyle\binom{n}{k}$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\binom{n+1}{k+1}
&=\frac{n+1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}\\
&\color{#C00000}{\le}\frac{n+1}{k+1}\color{#C00000}{\left(\frac{en}{k}\right)^k}\\
&=\frac{n+1}{k+1}\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^k\left(\frac{en}{k+1}\right)^k\\
&\color{#C00000}{\le}\frac{n+1}{k+1}\color{#C00000}{e}\left(\frac{en}{k+1}\right)^k\\
&\color{#C00000}{\le}\frac{n+1}{k+1}e\left(\frac{e\color{#C00000}{(n+1)}}{k+1}\right)^k\\
&=\left(\frac{e(n+1)}{k+1}\right)^{k+1}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Using $(1)$ and $(2)$, we see that
$$
\binom{n}{k}\le\left(\frac{en}{k}\right)^k\tag{3}
$$
For $n\ge k\ge1$.

Comment: To me this is the _only_ correct answer (so far), and the only one that uses _any_ property of the number $e$ (other than $e>1$).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: in AmWhy's answer, right after the inductive hypothesis,
$$
e\ge\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^k
$$
is used; it is just a bit more obscured.

Comment: Well you are very generous. In similar situation when grading exams I would have to conclude "absent" rather than "obscured". One criterion one can apply is whether an argument ever uses a necessary ingredient, which as I said would be "where does one use that $e$ denotes $2.71828\ldots$ rather than some other real number?" here. But of course this is not an exam. Anyway, a nice proof.

Comment: robjohn: I edited to make explicit what was a "bit more obscured" in my ealier post, the obscurity referenced by @MarcvanLeeuwen. If you think that in editing, my answer resembles yours too closely, PLEASE, say the word, and I'll roll-back to the previous edit; I will have no objections to doing so.

Answer (score 5):

General approach for proof by induction on $k$, for a given $n$:

> $${n \choose k} \le \left({en \over k}\right)^k\tag{1}$$

First, we establish the base case $P(1)$: let $k = 1$ and show that the inequality holds.

Then we assume the inductive hypothesis, that is, assume the truth of $P(k)$, as given in $(1)$.

Then, *using the inductive hypothesis*, you test to see whether  $$P(k+1) = {n \choose k+1} \le \left({en \over k+1}\right)^{k+1}$$

The challenging part is the last: use what you know (having proved it without induction) to write $P(k+1)$ in terms of the assumed inductive hypothesis. Then it's simply manipulating to exhibit the final form of the inequality you are seeking to establish.

---

Update: You're on your way, and almost there, with your inductive step. Recall, as robjohn notes below your post, you want to prove $$\binom{n}{k+1} \leq \left(\frac{en}{k+1}\right)^{k+1}.$$
Making a few tweaks with respect to your work, we have that:

$$
\begin{align} \\
\binom{n}{k+1}
& = \frac{n}{k+1}\binom{n-1}{k}  \\ \\
& \leq \frac{n}{k+1} \left(\frac{e(n-1)}{k}\right)^k \quad\quad\quad\tag{inductive hypothesis} \\ \\
& = \frac{n}{k+1}\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^k \left(\frac{e(n - 1)}{k+1}\right)^k \\ \\
& \leq \frac{en}{k+1} \left(\frac{e(n-1)}{k+1}\right)^k \\ \\
& \leq \frac{en}{k+1} \left(\frac{en}{k+1}\right)^k \\ \\
& = \left(\frac{en}{k+1}\right)^{k+1} \\ \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks. You have probably misunderstood me slightly. I know what induction is, but I cannot find the key step to bring it to the right form. Is it straightforward from this point?

Comment: OK got it, thanks!

Comment: I notice that my argument is similar to yours (+1). If you wish, I will delete mine. I posted it since I have included some more detail.

Comment: I skipped some steps, @Marc, though it can easily be justified, as per robjohn. And given robjohn's post, to go in and "fill in the details" I left out NOW, at this point, would *appear* inappropriate. *But you've raised a good point, and I would not submit as is, if I were assigned this problem.* But let me be clear, my original intent was to point out an oversight of the OP, not to do the proof for him/her.

Comment: @Marc I went ahead to make explicit what I did not make explicit in my earlier post. If robjohn doesn't object to this edit, it will stand as is, else I'll roll back and attempt to describe in words what was too obscure in my earlier step following the inductive hypothesis.

Answer (score 3):

Induction step:

$${n \choose k+1}={n\over k+1}{n-1 \choose k} \le {n\over k+1} \left({e(n-1) \over k}\right)^k \le {n\over k} \left({en \over k}\right)^k \le \left({en \over k}\right)^{k+1}$$

Comment: Nicely done.${}$

Comment: The estimate is supposed to be
$$
\binom{n}{k+1}\le\left(\frac{en}{k+1}\right)^{k+1}
$$
is it not?

Comment: You're right. Your solution is the correct one.